# Database Dependencies - Database Design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a database with the following attribute dependencies:
Approach 1: A <- B <- C <-D
Approach 2: A <- B, {A,B} < C, {A,B,C} <- D;

- With the first approach, attribute D is dependent on attribute C, C on B and B on A.
- With second approach, attribute D can be gotten directly from A.

Please I need your help on which approach is better. Thanks

**EDIT**

Sample tables for approach 1

Country_info
-------------  , state info, city_info, village_info

id | country_id | name

TABLE PAIRS

### country_state

id | state_id | country_id

### state_division

id | division_id | state_id

### village_division

id | village_id | division_id

Now, I have the id of a village and I want to know the name of the country in which it belongs. I will have to look for the division, state before arriving at the country.

With the second approach, the village table will have the division_id, state_id and the country_id.

Thanks!

Comment: what do U mean by 'attribute' - column? and 'dependence' is foregin key?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Yes

Comment: How many tables you have? What column they have?

Comment: I have 4 tables say A-D; each with a foreign key through the hierarchy

Comment: Ok - to choose right design you must also give us information about your purpose. You must specify what is the meaning of each table in system - and depends on that information we can give you some hint - because in some cases first approach is better but for other cases the second approach is better

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I've done an edit.

Answer (score 1):

If village is "main" obiect which will be used very often (and it's relations to other tables will be also often used) then by using second approach you will reduce number of code lines and increase performance (eg. in filtering villages by country).

Answer (score 1):

KISS.

Table 1:  A business/person/etc has an address and a City.

Table 2:  The City also includes the Viliage, State, Province, Country_code, Postal_code, whatever.

Normalizing each layer is overkill.

If you have half a dozen tables, imagine the number of `JOINs` needed to get all the parts of the address!